# Count Max number of day continious overdraff

Tags: oracle, select

```
Date  | Account |  Amount   | Count max number of day continuous < 0     |
  1   |   1001  | 100        | 0   |
  2   |   1001  | -100       | 1   |
  3   |   1001  | -100       | 2   |
  4   |   1001  | 100        | 2   |
  5   |   1001  | -100       | 2   |
  6   |   1001  | -100       | 2   |
  7   |   1001  | -100       | 3   |
  8   |   1001  | -100       | 4   |
  9   |   1001  | 100        | 4   |
```

I have sample data. I want have column "Count max number of day continuous < 0". How i can select it in database oracle

Comment: what it the logic behind `Count max number of day continuous < 0`

Answer (score 0):

In order to find continuous periods you can use [Tabibitosian method](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680). Then use analytical `count` and finally `max`:

```
select date_, account, amount, 
       max(cnt) over (partition by account order by date_) max_overdraft_period
  from (
    select date_, account, amount, 
           count(case when amount <= 0 then 1 end) 
                 over (partition by account, grp order by date_) cnt
      from (
        select date_, account, amount, 
               date_ - sum(case when amount <= 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
                           over (partition by account order by date_) grp
          from t ))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d95752a4b3026055cec228b3ef10fb85])</sup>**

I assumed that dates are continuous, if not then use row numbering at first.

Comment: My DB have data one day (day by day). How i can caculate it

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was away. I think you could make union of the tables which you need and maybe create a view. If this does not help please edit your question and add relevant informations there. I answered on original question, I may or may not know the answer on another so please add all details when asking.